# Alternative to using a global variable in a class?

Tags: php, database, oop, class, pdo

I have started to learn how to use OOP and have created a user authorisation class to check if the user exists etc. Currently I am connected to the database by using the global variable `$dbh` which is a PDO connection. I've heard that using global variables in this way isn't good practice but am not sure how I can improve it, would I just pass the `$dbh` variable into the method that requires it when connecting to a database and why exactly is this not considered good practice?

Here is some code I am using:

Database PDO connection included in calling program:

```
//test the connection
    try{
        //connect to the database
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=oopforum","root", "usbw");

    //if there is an error catch it here
    } catch( PDOException $e ) {
        //display the error
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

The class that requires the database connection:

```
class Auth{

        private $dbh;

        function __construct(){

            global $dbh;
            $this->dbh = $dbh;
        }

        function validateLogin($username, $password){

            // create query (placing inside if statement for error handling)
            if($stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM oopforumusers WHERE username = ? AND password = ?")){

                $stmt->bind_param(1, $username);
                $stmt->bind_param(2, $password);
                $stmt->execute();


                // Check rows returned
                $numrows = $stmt->rowCount();

                //if there is a match continue
                if( $numrows > 0 ){
                    $stmt->close();
                    return TRUE;
                }else{
                    $stmt->close();
                    return FALSE;
                }

            }else{
                die('ERROR: Could not prepare statement');
            }

        }


        function checkLoginStatus(){

            if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){

                return TRUE;

            }else{

                return FALSE;

            }

        }

        function logout(){

            session_destroy();
            session_start();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should pass the PDO connection to the constructor:

```
function __construct($dbh) {
    $this->dbh = $dbh;
}
```

The connection is called a *dependency* of your class because obviously your class needs it in order to carry out its function. Good practice dictates that your class should make it *explicit* that this dependency exists; this is achieved by making it a mandatory constructor parameter.

If you instead pull in the dependency from a global variable you create several issues:

- It's not clear at all to a user of your class that there is a dependency in the first place
- Your class is now coupled to the global variable, which means that the variable cannot be removed or renamed without breaking the program
- You have created the preconditions for "action at a distance": modifying the value of the global variable causes another (seemingly unrelated) part of your application to change behavior

Comment: What if I need create instant of a class inside a class that I pass DB connection to constructor of it?

Comment: On my user class, i call `new User()`.. and now how i send Db connection to it?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply pass it to constructor.

```
function __construct($connection){
         $this->connection = $connection;
}
```

When you create object you do:

```
$obj = new Class($dbh);
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass the database object in via the constructor.  PHP's object model means that = creates new references to the same instance of an object.

```
class ThingThatDependsOnDatabase
{
    private $db = NULL;

    public function __construct (PDO $db)
    {
        $this -> db = $db;
    }

    public function selectSomething ($id)
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?;'
        $this -> db -> prepare ($sql);
        // And so on
    }
}
```

This is an example of a pattern called [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), because the things your class depend on are injected via a method (setter, constructor, etc).